# How to change the image button back to the previous image when user click the button again in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a seat reservation system, I have seating chart in my asp.net webpages. When user click on one of the seat, it will change to another image.

I have did that. However, I cannot figured out how to do if the user click the same seat again, the image will change to previous image meaning that user did not want to reserve that seat anymore.

Any method can do this?
I change my image upon the first click by code below:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "seatreserved.png";
}
```

Thank you if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Can save something in Button's Tag property.

Comment: What you SHOULD be doing is keeping a list of reserved seats. That way, if  the reserved seat list is adding a seat, you set the image. If you are REMOVING a seat - you set the other image. You determine whether you are adding or removing based on whether or not the seat is in the list at the time of clicking

Comment: Oh so meaning that I can create a method for this and called in the button click method ? @QuintinBalsdon

Comment: What I am suggesting is using your model to correctly reflect what is displayed on the screen. What I see is you modifying UI in the code, but where are you creating a list of reservations for the user? How do you know which seats are being reserved? Where you going to go through and look at the images?

Comment: Oh yes I have an array for the seat list, when the seat was reserved, it will turn true, when the seat was not reserved, it will back false again, is this okay ? @QuintinBalsdon

Comment: It sounds like that list should be dictating what image is displayed for the button. :)

Comment: I got what you mean :) Will do like this! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code as above, just wrap it in an if statement:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(ImageButton1.ImageUrl != "seatreserved.png")
    {
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "seatreserved.png";
    }
    else
    {
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "seatNotreserved.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check which is the currend picture and **IF** it's pic1.png **set(=)** it to pic2.png